# How do I make a plotly graph where I can change the coloring parameter interactively?

Tags: python, plotly

In plotly express I can create scatter plots using data.frames easily:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", log_x=True, color='continent')
```

Is there a way to add a dropdown menu into the plot so I can choose also the other parameters as a color? Doing so should not reset the zoom.

I could not figure out how to do that except by using a dash app, but I still have some problems there: The hover does not change and it is not possible to switch between categorical and numerical coloring. Let me give you what I have achieved so far:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder()
df["moreData1"] = np.random.normal(size = len(df))

labels = df.columns[df.dtypes=="float64"]
#labels = df.columns

options = [{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in labels]
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x="gdpPercap",
                 y="lifeExp", 
                 log_x=True, 
                 color=labels[1],
                 #color='continent',
                 render_mode='webgl'
                )

# somehow this line prevents from resetting the zoom. Do not really understand why.
fig.update_layout(uirevision='some_unique_value')
# Define the layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='color-dropdown',
        options=options,
        value=labels[-1]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='scatter-plot',
        figure=fig
    )
])

# Define the callback to update the scatter plot based on the selected color
@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('color-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_scatter_plot(selected_color):
    fig.update_traces(
        marker_color=df[selected_color]
    )
    return fig

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8052)
```

It works somehow, but I would like to have two improvements: I want to be able to display categoric values too (does not work as you can see by setting `labels = df.columns` instead of only numeric columns.

And more importantly I want to show the coloring information in hover.

There is no need in using a dash app, I think I would be even happier about a pure plotly-plot.

Comment: In the callback you need to rebuild the figure using the selected color : `return px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", log_x=True, color=selected_color)`.

Comment: But this way, the zoom is not kept on redraw.

Comment: You can reapply the current zoom range, which you can grab from the figure's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback, you need to rebuild entirely the figure using the `selected_color` (the figure can contain either 1 trace per continent, or 1 trace per country, etc., there is no trace update).

Also, in order to preserve the zoom range between updates, you can read the current range using a `State()` and apply it to the new figure.

```
# Define the callback to update the scatter plot based on the selected color
@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-plot', 'figure'),
    Input('color-dropdown', 'value'),
    State('scatter-plot', 'figure'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_scatter_plot(selected_color, fig):

    xrange = fig['layout']['xaxis']['range']
    yrange = fig['layout']['yaxis']['range']

    fig = px.scatter(df,
                     x="gdpPercap",
                     y="lifeExp",
                     log_x=True,
                     color=selected_color,
                     render_mode='webgl'
                     )

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=xrange, yaxis_range=yrange)

    return fig
```